# WMI query doesn't update

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caching, wmi

I'm using WPF app for developing a testing tool.
One of the buttons suppose to run this flow:

1. Installing an exe that install a driver.
2. running WMI query to see if the driver was installed.
3. Uninstall the driver.
4. running WMI query to see if the driver was uninstalled.

The problem is that after running one query, it seems like the results are caching somewhere in the app and it doesn't update, so the function returns that the driver is still installed even when i see it doesn't (manual checking in device manager and even running a query manually with power shell while breaking point in the app).

Is there any way to clear the cache or refresh the results?

Thanks.

This is the functions that checks for the driver with WMI query:

```
private void CheckIfDeviceInstalled(string driver, bool shouldBeInstalled)
{
    main_wtl.writeToConsoleAndLog("Searching for " + driver + " driver...", ConsoleColor.White);

    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_pnpsigneddriver");
    query.Condition = "DeviceName = '"+driver+"'";
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    var drivers = searcher.Get();

    if (shouldBeInstalled)
    {
        if (drivers.Count > 0)
            main_wtl.writeToConsoleAndLog(driver + " Driver exists.", ConsoleColor.Green);
        else
            main_wtl.writeToConsoleAndLog(driver + " Driver could not be found.", ConsoleColor.Red);
    }
    else
    {
        if (drivers.Count > 0)
            main_wtl.writeToConsoleAndLog(driver + " Driver exists.", ConsoleColor.Red);
        else
            main_wtl.writeToConsoleAndLog(driver + " Driver could not be found.", ConsoleColor.Green);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if the driver is still loaded into the system process. Perhaps it could not be unloaded while it was in use and it will be uninstalled finally only after a reboot? Although you might have uninstalled the files the uninstall might still be pending due to locked files.

Comment: It's not a problem with a specific driver... It's the same for all of the drivers. No reboot required because i can see that the driver isn't in the the device manager anymore while i'm in breaking point (after uninstall through the code). @AloisKraus

Comment: Are you sure that the files of the driver have been removed and are no longer in use? In any case you should check out Driver Store: https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer which should return up to date information. If this one works you can use this approach to enumerate installed drivers.

Comment: @AloisKraus I ran my code with your tool in the backround and checked with break points (After install and atfer unisntall) if the INFs are in the list, and its there after install and remove after uninstall, which means that the install and that uninstall work (And the WMI query still return the results after the first run).